# Algorithm for condensing/consolidating number combinations

Tags: algorithm, combinations

Using a horse race betting scenario, say I have a number of separate bets for predicting the first 4 finishers of the race (superfecta).

The bets are as follows...

```
1/2/3/4  
1/2/3/5  
1/2/4/3  
1/2/4/5  
1/2/5/3  
1/2/5/4
```

What I want to do is combine or condense these separate combinations as much as possible.  For the bets above, they can be all condensed into 1 line...

```
1/2/3,4,5/3,4,5
```

But if I removed the last bet from the list: 1/2/5/4 ...

```
1/2/3/4  
1/2/3/5  
1/2/4/3  
1/2/4/5  
1/2/5/3
```

The condensed bets would instead have to now be 2 lines:

```
1/2/3,4/3,4,5  
1/2/5/3
```

What would algorithm look like for this?

Comment: Is the rule that each slot in the condensed line gets the union of the numbers that appear in that slot in the separate bets? In your example, condensed set exactly represents the separate bets, but in general it would also represent bets not in the original set. Is this okay? Or do you intend some other rule?

Comment: I edited my question hopefully explaining the rules better and answering your comment.

Comment: That clarifies the problem quite a bit. It's kind of like the set covering problem, but not quite. Interesting problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it easiest to think about this kind of thing with pretty pictures.  How about we try to build some graphs?

### First example

```
1/2/3/4  
1/2/3/5  
1/2/4/3  
1/2/4/5  
1/2/5/3  
1/2/5/4
```

...could look like this, in graph form:

[image: example 1 before]

Each path from top to bottom (e.g. `1->2->4->3`) corresponds to a row in your initial format.

If we start with that graph, then (perhaps) we can run a little algorithm on the graph that will simplify it in the way you're looking for.  Here's what we'll try:

- Start at the top of the graph, and move down level by level.  (The first level contains only the blue node `1`.)
- For each node in the current level, count the number of children.  If there is only one child, skip the node.  (Since blue node `1` only has one child, we'll skip to green node `2`.)
- For each of the multiple children, construct a set that contains that child and its grandchildren.  (The red node `3` has a set `{3,4,5}`, red `4` has a set `{3,4,5}`, and red `5` has a set `{3,4,5}`.)
- If any of these sets are identical, **replace the associated children/grandchildren with a single node containing the children, pointing to a grandchild that contains the set**.  (Since all three red nodes have identical sets, they all get replaced.)

[image: example 1 after]

---

### Second example

```
1/2/3/4  
1/2/3/5  
1/2/4/3  
1/2/4/5  
1/2/5/3
```

...could look like this, in graph form:

[image: example 2 before]

The red nodes `3` and `4` have identical sets (i.e. `{3,4,5}`), so they get replaced.  Red node `5` doesn't have the same set as red nodes `3` and `4`, so we leave it alone.

[image: example 2 after]

As before, each path through the simplified tree represents one row of your output.

*(I haven't covered what happens if you replace children/grandchildren when there are great-grandchildren.  It could be that you should actually start at the bottom row and work your way upwards.)*

Comment: Wow, thank you for taking the time to illustrate this.  This has put me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

by F#

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic

let data =
  [|
    "1/2/3/4"
    "1/2/3/5"
    "1/2/4/3"
    "1/2/4/5"
    "1/2/5/3"
    "1/2/5/4"
  |]
let conv (xs:string []) =
  let xs = xs |> Array.map (fun x -> x.Split('/'))
  let len = xs.[0] |> Array.length
  let sa = Array.init len (fun _ -> new SortedSet<string>())
  xs |> Array.iter (fun xa -> xa |> Array.iteri (fun i x -> sa.[i].Add(x) |>ignore))
  String.Join("/", sa |> Array.map (fun x -> if Seq.length x = 1 then Seq.head x else String.Join(",", x |> Seq.toArray)))

let _ = 
  conv data |> printfn "%s"
//result:1/2/3,4,5/3,4,5

  //use 0-3 and 4 element of data
  [|data.[0..3]; data.[4..4] |]
  |> Array.map (fun x -> conv x)
  |> Array.iter (printfn "%s")
(* result:
1/2/3,4/3,4,5
1/2/5/3
*)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I'm not familiar with the programming language here, but I think what this is doing is just combining the unique numbers in each position and building a single list.  I appended my original question showing that you can't do this.

Comment: If it is the same question and the previous question, I have misunderstood the question. but it belongs to seem arbitrary. E.g. The reason to be ([1/2/3,4/3,4,5], [1/2/5/3]) instead of ([1/2/3/4,5],[1/2/4/3,5],[1/2/5/3])?